# Incorporating a Worksheetfunction.right in this naming convention?

Tags: excel, vba

I have files being saved off a master file. Unfortunately, the character limit is coming close to exceeding excels limitations and I wanted to see if it's possible to implement this formula as a worksheet function in VBA?

formula: `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(E2," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))`

vba line in order to save my file: `.SaveAs Filename:=Basepath & dt & "_" & Manager & "_Employee Impacts File", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`

I was thinking something like: `& application.worksheetfunction.right(Manager," ",rept(" ",100)),100)) & "_Employee Impacts File"`, but that's not working for me, getting a syntax error

Comment: You need `WorksheetFunction` in front of `rept` too, if you plan to use it.

Comment: editor keeps highlighting the last `100` in this line `& application.worksheetfunction.right(Manager," ",worksheetfunction.rept(" ",100)),100))`

Comment: By "if you plan to use it," I also meant that there's probably a cleaner VBA solution that doesn't resort to worksheet formulas, to be honest.

Comment: `Split(Range("E2")," ")(Ubound(Split(Range("E2")," "))`

Comment: @ScottCraner I'll need it to reference the `Manager` variable, so would I do:

`Split(Manager," ")(UBound(Split(Manager," "))`?

Comment: @NidenK - Yes. You can replace `Manager` in Scott's example

Comment: @ScottCraner this: `Split(Manager, " ")(UBound(Split(Manager, " ")))` worked perfectly, can you provide an answer so I can mark it solved? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using VBA, use VBA.  There are time that `WorkSheetFunction` are needed but they are rare and slower than the native functions in vba.

In this case we can use `Split()` to split on the space and return the last one with UBound

```
Split(Manager, " ")(UBound(Split(Manager, " ")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `mid` and `InStrRev` ;o) like so:

`mid(Range("E2").value,InStrRev(Range("E2").value,chr(32)))`